# How can i create a plist file from these arrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, plist, nscollectionview

I have a NSCollectionView that can read data like this code:

```
    self.contents = @[
                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 1",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$20.90",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-1.png"},

                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 2",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$10.90",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-3.png"},

                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 3",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$9810.90",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-4.png"},

                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 4",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$100.90",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-5.png"},

                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 5",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$109.19",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-1.png"},

                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 6",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$910.90",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-6.png"},

                  @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 7",
                    @"itemPrice":@"$632.90",
                    @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-7.png"},

                  ];
```

My question is, how I can turn this code into a plist file, so I can get the data of the plist file into the NSCollectionView by using this code:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"legue" ofType:@"plist"];
self.contents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Comment: Since it's already written like that, you can use `writeToFile:` in Desktop (for instance) in order to create a plist file, and use it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *filename = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject];
// your plist path
NSString *path = [filename stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"legue.plist"];
[contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
// test it
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"legue.plist" ofType:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",str); // str = nil;
```

So you should create a new plist file,then you can use [NSBundle mainBundle].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function (objective-C) to create the plist file:

```
+ (void) writeToPlist {
    NSArray* contents = @[
                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 1",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$20.90",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-1.png"},

                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 2",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$10.90",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-3.png"},

                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 3",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$9810.90",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-4.png"},

                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 4",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$100.90",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-5.png"},

                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 5",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$109.19",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-1.png"},

                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 6",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$910.90",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-6.png"},

                          @{@"itemTitle":@"Product 7",
                            @"itemPrice":@"$632.90",
                            @"itemImage":@"PastedGraphic-7.png"},

                          ];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,

                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"legue.plist"];

    [contents writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new plist file and design your plist below image:

[image]